# Capturing onClick event when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, symfony, twig

I created a form which collects data to either launch an external process (bash script) or to make a database query (using queryBuilder). Since both procedure could take some time, I would like to update the submit button, **as soon as it is clicked**, with  a message (like 'Processing..., please wait') or an icon (like the animated icons of FontAwesome). Here is the function I set in my Controller class (Symfony2):

```
public function inputAction(Request $request)
    {

        $form = $this->createForm(new InputType());
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
        {           
            $data = $form->getData();
            $cmd = '... my command using $data and taking some time ... ';
            $process = new Process($cmd);
            $process->setTimeout(120);
            $process->run();

// Alternative DB query
//          $qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
//              ->createQueryBuilder();
//          $query = $qb->select('COUNT(p)')
//              ->add('from','myBundle:Ec p')
//              ->add('where', 'p.ec LIKE :ec')
//              ->setParameter('ec', $data['..'].'%')
//              ->getQuery();
//              
//          $result = $query->getSingleScalarResult();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('_input');

        }

        return $this->render('myBundle:Default:form.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

    }
```

I thus added a JQuery call in my template

```
{% extends 'myBundle:Default:input.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form %}
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

{{ parent() }}
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.btn-default').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prepend('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>  ');
    });
});
</script>

{%endblock %}
```

But the message or the icon is not displayed when the button is clicked. It is only displayed if I stop the process in the browser. I also tried the 'submit' event, with no more success, while 'mouseover' is perfectly working.

EDIT 1

Following the advice from @Micha, when I modified JS like that:

```
$(function() {
    $('.btn-default').attr('prepend', 'false')
    $('.btn-default').on('click', function(e) {
    if($('.btn-default').attr('prepend') == 'false'){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.btn-default').attr('prepend','true');
        $(this).prepend('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>  ');
        $(this).trigger('click');
    }
    });
});
```

I see that the DOM is updated and the query (or the process) launched, but the prepend text or icon is not actually displayed in the browser.

Comment: Does your submit button has `.btn-default` class?

Comment: how about setting a flag (eg. "iconPrepended"). its default is `false`. when the button is clicked and `iconPrepended == false`, use `event.preventDefault();`, set `iconPrepended = true`, prepend your icon and call `$(this).trigger('click');`. Does it work then?

Comment: @HarryBomrah: yes, it has (and the onmouseover event works well)

Comment: I think your form is getting submitted as soon as u click on the btn. add `return false` to ur click event listener.

Comment: @Micha : it almost works... See my edit: when I look at the DOM, I see the 'prepend' occurring, but it is not displayed !?

Comment: @ptocquin to be honest, i do not know what causes this problem. could you instead place the `<i>` element in your button right from the start (hard coded in template), give it an id, use the style `display:none;` and then upon click just use `$('#yourId').fadeIn(0);`? that might do the trick

Comment: @Micha no more success with fadeIn(); Surprisingly, sometimes the icon appears (but not animated) but most of the time it doesn't appear at all. So it seems that it is something with the way the browser capture the DOM update ?

Comment: @Micha... while writing my last comment, I thought about testing other browsers (I was using Safari)... No problem with my original code in Firefox and Chrome... Grrrrrrrrrr !

Answer (score 0):

How about **preventDefault()** and then **submit()** the form from in the click function?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.btn-default').on('click', function(event) {
    event.PreventDefault();
    $(this).prepend('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>  ');
    $(#my-form).submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. I suppose I can't call JS in the core of my php code. The code shown is a function inside a Symfony2 controller class.

Comment: Okay then thanks for explaining, I have revised the answer above, I hope this works! Let me know if not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was facing is apparently only occurring with Safari. My original code (and most of the proposed solutions by @Micha and @chris-rogers) are perfectly working in Chrome and Firefox.